# Linux kernel - kthread_stop always returning -EINTR?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, kernel

I'm doing a bit of testing on the Linux kthread functions, and have the following module:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kthread.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/smp.h>
#include <linux/cpumask.h>
#include <linux/err.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

int function(void *data)
{
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "CPU: %u\n", smp_processor_id());

    return 0;
}

/* Function executed upon loading driver */
int __init init_module(void)
{
    unsigned int cpu;

    printk(KERN_DEBUG "init\n");

    for_each_present_cpu(cpu)
    {
        struct task_struct *thread = kthread_create(function, NULL, "Thread %u", cpu);

        if (!IS_ERR(thread))
        {
            int result;

            /* Bind the thread to the current core */
            kthread_bind(thread, cpu);

            /* Start the thread */
            wake_up_process(thread);

            /* Wait for the thread function to complete */
            result = kthread_stop(thread);

            printk(KERN_DEBUG "Thread %u stopped with result %d\n", cpu, result);
        }
        else
        {
            printk(KERN_ALERT "Could not create a thread bound to core number %u\n", cpu);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

/* Function executed when unloading module */
void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "exit\n");
}
```

From what I understood, I should be able to see all the "CPU: ..." prints before init_module ends. However, kthread_stop is always returning -EINTR, as if wake_up_process wasn't actually being called. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

an educated guess: the thread loading the module never relinquishes the cpu it is running on, so in particular the thread you bound to this very cpu never gets a chance to run in the first place. this happens because kernel preemption is disabled (see CONFIG_PREEMPT). try binding to a different cpu or yielding.

Comment: Makes sense. However, the comment atop kthread_stop says "Sets kthread_should_stop() for @k to return true, wakes it, and waits for it to exit". The "waits for it to exit" part makes it sound like the caller thread does relinquish the CPU.

Comment: cmon man. in that case it may be by the time the child gets to run for the first time the flag is already set and your routine never gets called. you have the code, you can easily add printks to check. see kthread. there are 2 EINTRs there.

Comment: Where are the two EINTRs? In any case, if what you say is true then the comment is misleading at best. The way it's phrased makes it sound like it's similar to pthread_join.

Comment: in the function named "kthread", the starting point of all kernel threads created using this method. i don't see anything misleading in the wording. waking the thread up does not mean it has to be able to reach the func you passed.